# Why is my create form request throwing off a 404 exception in Laravel5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

So I am working with a Laravel 5 installation and like a good programmer I am trying to get the validation logic out of my controller using the new Form Requests feature in Laravel.

So I went ahead and created a form request called CreateTenantRequest like so:

```
php artisan make:request CreateTenantRequest
```

By default it returns a `false` in the `authorize` method and it works correctly. If I fire a request, it says forbidden. But then I updated the rules and I set the `authorize` method to `true` and now when I fire the same request from Postman, it says:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Which is ridiculous because when I change it to  false, it returns forbidden fine?

What am I missing or doing wrong?

And although this wouldn't matter I guess but my rules array is as follows:

```
return [
    // Tenant details
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'username' => 'required|max:255|unique:tenant',
    // Tenant Admin details
    'first_name' => 'required',
    'last_name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
];
```

Routes file:

```
<?php

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function(){
    Route::post('authenticate', 'Auth\AuthController@authenticate');

    // SuperAdmin Group
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Archive', 'middleware' => 'superadmin'], function(){
        Route::resource('tenants', 'TenantController');
        Route::get('tenants/{id}/users', 'TenantController@showUsersForTenant');
    });

    // Tenant Group
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Tenant'], function(){
        Route::resource('roles', 'RoleController');
        Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    });

    // Remove before production
    // Only for testing purposes
    Route::get('test', function(){
        // return JWTAuth::parseToken()->getPayload()->get('username');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you include your Routes file? When an NotFoundHttpException appears most of the time something is wrong in your Routes file.

Comment: Do you see anything that might be messing it up? And plus if the routes file was the problem, why it working with the false argument? *confused emoticon*

Comment: What is the URL you are calling?

Comment: What happens if you return an empty array in your rules function?

Comment: @shock_gone_wild: Empty array is going through. Wow. Why is this happening? :O

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that you get redirected to a non existing url in case form request validation is failing

Comment: Could you add dd($this->getRedirectUrl()); at the beginning of your rules function and tell us, what your redirect url is ?

Comment: You're right about the redirection. I tested with valid credentials and it passes. The dd returned this: `"http://localhost:8000"`

Comment: But how do I correct this? How to get around this problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92220/discussion-between-shock-gone-wild-and-rohan).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So after a bid discussion with [shock_gone_wild](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3927116/shock-gone-wild), I realized that the request was not ajax and hence laravel was rerouting to the a url with the errors in session.

I was testing the API with Postman REST client and by default it sends basic HTTP requests but when a header is added like so:

```
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

It makes the request Ajax and then laravel checks to see if it is indeed ajax, so instead of routing to a url, it gave back the validation errors in JSON.

So anytime if anyone is creating a decoupled web service and trying to test it using Postman, do it with the header so that you can simulate actual ajax requests at your application.

Comment: Or can use ```Accept: application/json```